# Turn dictionary of lists into a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a Python 3 dictionary holding very long lists (30 million integers each). I would like to stitch all these lists into a single numpy array. How can I do this **efficiently**?

The following

```
np.array(my_dict.values())
```

doesn't seem to work (I get `array(dict_values([[...], [....]))` as opposed to a flat 1D numpy array).

Comment: in Python 3 just do `np.array(list(my_dict.values())).flatten()`

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a flat 1d array, you could just use `np.concatenate`:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
>>> np.concatenate(list(d.values()))
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

`list(my_dict.values())`

---

(commentary added)

`dict.values()` returns `view` not a list. Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
chn = chain.from_iterable(d.values())
np.array(list(chn))
```

Comment: +1 if he doesn't need any order based on the keys this was the fastest approach

Comment: `list(chn)` makes more sense than `[x for x in chn]`. It's faster, too.

Comment: for me (Python 3) `np.array(list(chain(d.values())))` works

Answer (score 1):

Allocate numpy arrays ahead of time:

```
my_dict = {0:[0,3,2,1], 1:[4,2,1,3], 2:[3,4,2,1]}
array = numpy.ndarray((len(my_dict), len(my_dict.values()[0]))
```

then you can insert them into the array like so:

```
for index, val in enumerate(my_dict.values()):
    arr[index] = val
>>> arr
array([[ 0.,  3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  2.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: This creates a multidimensional array not a 1d array as requested by the OP

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an ordered concatenation based on the keys:

```
np.array([d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())]).flatten()
```

if you don't need any order based on the keys, @Padraic Cunningham's approach was the fastest based on my timings here...